# spawn yarnpkg ENOENT

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, yarnpkg

This happens when I run **expo install expo-permissions**

It explicitly returns me

> Installing 1 SDK 35.0.0 compatible native module using Yarn.
>
> yarn add expo-permissions@~7.0.0
>
> spawn yarnpkg ENOENT
>
> Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

Which is strange because I don't normally use Yarn. I use NPM to install dependencies.

I know this error has to do with my files or some path not being configured correctly. What I don't know is which path it is that I have to change and how to do so.

Please let me know if there is any other relevant info that I should add here.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Comment: Simple solution: delete `yarn.lock` file if you don't have yarn installed

Comment: @ShivamJha - This helped me. Simplest solution to this issue

Answer (score 49):

I had the same problem as you my solution and you perform the installation of yarn via npm:
`npm i -g yarn`
I believe this error is caused because he cannot find the symbolic link for yarnpkg. When executing this command, yarn will be updated and linked.

Answer (score 27):

You can just pass the flag --npm after the command.

```
expo install [package-name] --npm
```

Comment: That´s the best answer because you don´t have to install Yarn to solve the problem. Just add the arg --npm to the command and all went fine. works with "expo update --npm" too.

Answer (score 11):

Best solution for this would be using `--npm flag`

Example:

```
expo install pkname --npm,
expo update --npm,
expo upgrade --npm,
```

This is happened because you haven't executed `yarn install` or `yarn` command.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I tried many ways and finally, I found the solution.
The issue was different yarn package version.
So first of all, you need to upgrade yarn version lastest.

open terminal and type the following.

1. npm install --global yarn
2. expo update

Hope this solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. You should install `yarn` in your system, since that's what Expo CLI is trying to execute to install packages. For me my issue was that I did had `yarn` but I had an old version. I had to update my yarn version to 1.19.0. If you install this version it should work correctly.

I recommend using [yvm](https://yvm.js.org/docs/overview) to install and manage different versions of yarn. After you install `yvm` it is as easy to install `yarn` as `yvm install <version>`, so in this case you would do `yvm install 1.19.0`. And if you ever have to change versions because another project doesn't work with 1.19.0 (sometimes it happens) you can just install another version and change between versions by doing `yvm use <version>`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Latest Yarn Installation ([from here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable))

`curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

```
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn

sudo apt update && sudo apt install --no-install-recommends yarn
```

Add this to your profile: `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-[version]/bin"` (the path may vary depending on where you extracted Yarn to)
In the terminal, log in and log out for the changes to take effect

`yarn --version` checks if the version is latest (1.0+).

Then `expo update <version>` (ex: 36.0.0)

**Concideration:**
Do not forget to check if you give attention to similar warning: "*warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn.*"

Answer (score 0):

"spawn yarnpkg ENOENT" usually indicates that the system cannot find the "yarnpkg" command.

```
npm i -g corepack
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For nextjs you can try this as I found out that I am npx not yarn same as how I start npx expo start

```
npx expo update
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same error. I resolved by passing the flag `--npm` after the command.

```
expo install [package-name] --npm
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answer.